# Why should i ever use XMLLIst instead of a plain simple XML?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

Why should i use XMLList instead of XML. In other words, what an XMLList can do, that a simple plain XML class can't do ? After all, every XMLList is an XML only. ( I am peculiar about XML, as other list structures like Arraylist are somewhat different in case )

Thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that an [XMLList](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XMLList.html) is a collection of [XML](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html) document.  IT could be a subset, or it could be a collection of different XML elements.  To quote the XMLList docs:

> An XMLList object can represent one or more XML objects or elements
>   (including multiple nodes or attributes), so you can call methods on
>   the elements as a group or on the individual elements in the
>   collection.

You can wrap also an XMLList inside an [XMLLIstCollection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/XMLListCollection.html) and use it as a dataProvider for a list-based object in Flex.

This section of the [Adobe Docs on working with XML](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ff5.html) should help.

Comment: Additionally, most of the xml methods, such as child(), attribute(), etc., return an XMLList, so if you want to use the full power of e4x, you don't have much choice but to use XMLList

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to extract specific data from XML by using recursion:

```
public static function getNodesByName(myXML_:XMLList, nodeName_:String) : XMLList {
    var result:XMLList = new XMLList();
    for (var i1:Number = 0; i1 < myXML_.children().length(); i1++ ) {
        if (myXML_.children()[i1].name() == nodeName_) {
            result += myXML_.children()[i1].valueOf();
        } else if (myXML_.children()[i1].children()) { 
            result += getNodesByName(XMLList(myXML_.children()[i1].valueOf()), nodeName_);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This algorithm returns a list of nodes that meet specific requirement, in this case the nodes that have the same name. As you can see, the list makes easier to manipulate XML structure before you will turn it into new XML document.